# MobileFirst Server - Application Center Configure Ant Task (configure-appcenter-liberty-mysql.xml) Error

Tags: ant, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-appcenter

I'm trying to install & configure the application center for MobileFirst Server using the ant task to install. Prior to the install task I was able to use the database task to create necessary tables in the app center database.

I get the error mentioned in the logs below when running

```
ant -f configure-appcenter-liberty-mysql.xml install
```

#### Ref

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/appcenter/t_ac_deploy_cons_serv_ant_tasks.html?lang=en

### Ant Script Output

```
root@ubuntu:/opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/ApplicationCenter/configuration-samples# sudo ant -v  -f configure-appcenter-liberty-mysql-edited.xml install
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on April 8 2014
Buildfile: /opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/ApplicationCenter/configuration-samples/configure-appcenter-liberty-mysql-edited.xml
Detected Java version: 1.7 in: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Detected OS: Linux
parsing buildfile /opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/ApplicationCenter/configuration-samples/configure-appcenter-liberty-mysql-edited.xml with URI = file:/opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/ApplicationCenter/configuration-samples/configure-appcenter-liberty-mysql-edited.xml
Project base dir set to: /opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/ApplicationCenter/configuration-samples
parsing buildfile jar:file:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml with    URI = jar:file:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
Build sequence for target(s) `install' is [install]
Complete build sequence is [install, help, minimal-update, databases, uninstall, ]

install:
[installApplicationCenter] Logging output of task <installApplicationCenter> to file /root/.mobilefirst_platform_server/configuration-logs/installApplicationCenter_2016_04_20_22_42_09.log
[installApplicationCenter] Copying /opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/tools/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar to /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/shared/resources/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar
[installApplicationCenter] Copying /opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/tools/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar to /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/shared/resources/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar
[installApplicationCenter] Copying /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/servers/simpleServer/server.xml to /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/servers/simpleServer/server.xml.bak2
[installApplicationCenter] Modifying /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/servers/simpleServer/server.xml
[installApplicationCenter] Deleting /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/servers/simpleServer/server.xml.bak2

BUILD FAILED
/opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/ApplicationCenter/configuration-samples/configure-appcenter-liberty-mysql-edited.xml:74: An error occured while reading file /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/servers/simpleServer/server.xml. Error: null.
at com.ibm.worklight.config.ant.appserver.AppCenterAppServerTask.wasLibertyAugmentConfigFiles(AppCenterAppServerTask.java:654)
at com.ibm.worklight.config.ant.appserver.AppServerTask.configureAppServer(AppServerTask.java:4423)
at com.ibm.worklight.config.ant.appserver.AppServerTask.installItems(AppServerTask.java:4165)
at com.ibm.worklight.config.ant.appserver.AppCenterAppServerTask.installItems(AppCenterAppServerTask.java:1143)
at com.ibm.worklight.config.ant.appserver.AppServerTask.processItems(AppServerTask.java:4114)
at com.ibm.worklight.config.ant.appserver.AppCenterAppServerTask.buildAndProcessItems(AppCenterAppServerTask.java:1088)
at com.ibm.worklight.config.ant.appserver.AppServerTask.setupBuildAndProcessItems(AppServerTask.java:3064)
at com.ibm.worklight.config.ant.appserver.AppServerTask.doExecute(AppServerTask.java:307)
at com.ibm.worklight.config.ant.appserver.InstallApplicationCenterTask.execute(InstallApplicationCenterTask.java:28)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ibm.worklight.config.helper.appserver.WASLibertyAugmentServerXML.addAppCenterApplicationAndDataSourceElements(WASLibertyAugmentServerXML.java:1921)
at com.ibm.worklight.config.helper.appserver.WASLibertyAugmentServerXML.mainInstallApplicationCenter(WASLibertyAugmentServerXML.java:143)
at com.ibm.worklight.config.ant.appserver.AppCenterAppServerTask.wasLibertyAugmentConfigFiles(AppCenterAppServerTask.java:642)
... 25 more

Total time: 7 seconds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just based on the name of the Ant file you're using, and the pathnames displayed in in the message output you included, it looks like you started from the wrong sample Ant file - in other words, it appears that you are using Liberty Profile as your application server, but you started from the sample Ant file for use with WebSphere Application Server.

Assuming that is in fact the case, you should start with the sample configuration file "configure-appcenter-liberty-mysql.xml" instead.

Also, just as a hint - it appears that even with the file you are using, you modified the sample Ant file provided with MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1 "in place" and wrote it back to it's original filename and used it?  As mentioned in the documentation link you have in your question, it's actually recommended to make a **copy** of this file and work with the copy, rather than modifying the one we provide - that way, you'll always have the unmodified samples we provide, in case you want to refer to them, or use them as templates for a different server and/or different configuration.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it. I've tried now using the libery file and ends up giving the same kinda error. I updated the log in the main post.

Comment: Is there some way you can put the XML file somewhere where we can look at it (you can edit out passwords from the file, of course).  Is it possible that your Liberty Profile installation is not in /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty where the Ant file expects it to be, or that you haven't created the server "simpleServer" yet?

Comment: You will find my xml file at the link below. I have created simpleServer already and i have the mobile first operations console and analytics running on it already. I've also tried it on an alternative server other than simple server and still ends up being the same. The installation dir for liberty is correct.

http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=22270460609526927650

Answer (score 0):

I think you use Liberty Profile 8.5.5.9. There were some changes concerning the password decoding mechanism in this version that is no more compatible with MobileFirst.
Either you ask the IBM support for the APAR http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?crawler=1&uid=swg1PI61386, either you use Liberty 8.5.5.8.